# Extracting Date and Time from a long string

Tags: powershell

I was given a horribly formatted report that is supposed to be a CSV but it's really not so I have to import it and convert it. I have it converted and I have usable data however on the last column I have too much useless data and would like to extract the date and time from beginning of the string and from the end.

I have tried a few different ways but I can't seem to get what I want.

This is the code that I am running:

```
$csvPath = 'C:\Powershell\Test5.csv'
$csvData = Get-Content -Path $csvPath |
           Select-Object -Skip 1 |
           Out-String |
           ConvertFrom-Csv
$AuditTrail = $csvData | Select-Object "Approval History"

$AuditTrail | foreach {
    $entry = $_ -split 'Approved'
    $entry[-2]
}
```

The output is:

```
12/11/2018 10:20 AM  Submitted for approval by Joseph Star  12/11/2018 12:00 PM  
12/11/2018 05:16 PM  Submitted for approval by Joseph Star  12/12/2018 07:46 AM  
12/13/2018 09:41 AM  Submitted for approval by Joseph Star  12/13/2018 10:28 AM  
12/13/2018 05:16 PM  Submitted for approval by Joseph Star  12/14/2018 07:49 AM  
12/14/2018 05:22 PM  Submitted for approval by Joseph Star  12/18/2018 10:14 AM  
12/11/2018 10:06 AM  Submitted for approval by Jimmy Newton  12/14/2018 11:36 AM  
12/11/2018 06:33 PM  Submitted for approval by Jimmy Newton  12/14/2018 11:37 AM  
12/17/2018 10:28 AM  Submitted for approval by Jimmy Newton  12/18/2018 04:33 PM  
12/13/2018 03:31 PM  Submitted for approval by Jimmy Newton  12/14/2018 11:37 AM  
12/17/2018 10:33 AM  Submitted for approval by Jimmy Newton  12/18/2018 04:33 PM  
12/10/2018 05:59 PM  Submitted for approval by Stan Henry  12/11/2018 09:10 AM  
12/12/2018 10:59 AM  Submitted for approval by Stan Henry  12/14/2018 02:35 PM  
12/12/2018 05:01 PM  Submitted for approval by Stan Henry  12/14/2018 02:15 PM  
12/14/2018 10:12 AM  Submitted for approval by Stan Henry  12/14/2018 02:27 PM  
12/16/2018 11:24 PM  Submitted for approval by Stan Henry  12/19/2018 01:12 PM  
12/16/2018 11:25 PM  Submitted for approval by Stan Henry  12/18/2018 11:12 AM
```

From that output, I would like to take the first 19 characters (full date and Time) and store it into a Variable. I would then like to take the last 19 characters (full date and time) and store it into another variable.

Comment: use `.SubString()` to get each date string. then use `[datetime]::ParseExact()` to parse the date strings into datetime objects.

Comment: Split each line at 2 consecutive spaces, then parse the first and last field of each reasulting array into a `DateTime` value. We might be able to provide better suggestions if you showed us a representative sample of your actual input data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't rely on the two spaces separating the dates you can use a regex

```
$line = '12/11/2018 10:20 AM  Submitted for approval by Joseph Star  12/11/2018 12:00 PM'
[regex]$regex = '((0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/\-]\d{4} [01][0-9][\:][0-5][0-9] [AP]M)'
$date1, $date2 = [datetime[]] $regex.Matches($line).Value
```

based on mklement0's answer

Comment: As an aside: in PowerShell / C# there is no need to escape `/` as `\/ `in regular expressions.

Comment: This worked really well for me. Thank you very much, not all of them had the 2 spaces so this was reliable every time. Thank you so much, now I just need to study and learn how regex works, I don't understand it at all.

Answer (score 5):

The most concise solution is to split each line by *two spaces*, given that they separate both the date at the start and at the end, as [Ansgar Wiechers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630171/ansgar-wiechers) points out:

```
$line = '12/11/2018 10:20 AM  Submitted for approval by Joseph Star  12/11/2018 12:00 PM'
$date1, $date2 = [datetime[]] ($line -split '  ')[0,-1]
```

For a similarly concise *regex*-based solution, where dates are extracted based on *pattern matching*, see [seedie's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53884017/45375), which can be simplified as follows:

```
$line = '12/11/2018 10:20 AM  Submitted for approval by Joseph Star  12/11/2018 12:00 PM'
[regex] $regex = '\b\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2} (?:AM|PM)\b'
$date1, $date2 = [datetime[]] $regex.Matches($line).Value
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways that this can be achieved, the easiest I can think of, but also a bit of a 'quick and dirty' approach would be:

```
$string = "12/11/2018 10:20 AM  Submitted for approval by Joseph Star  12/11/2018 12:00 PM "
[datetime]$date1 = ($string -split " ")[0..2] -join " "
[datetime]$date2 = ($string -split " ")[-4..-1] -join " "
```

Essentially, just `-split` it into an array using the spaces `" "`, grab the first 3 items (`[0..2]`) from that array and then `-join` them back together into a string before casting to `[datetime]`. Likewise for the second date, but grab the last 3 items (`[-4..-1]`) from the array.

You can condense it into 1 line, if desired:

```
[datetime]$date1,[datetime]$date2 = (($string -split " ")[0..2] -join " "),(($string -split " ")[-4..-1] -join " ")
```

Which outputs:

```
[Fri 21 Dec 00:28:26] PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>$date1

11 December 2018 10:20:00

[Fri 21 Dec 00:30:01] PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>$date2

11 December 2018 12:00:00
```

If the strings ever change, or the dates aren't always the first 3 or last 3 sets of consecutive characters, then this will not work.

Comment: isn't `[-4..-1]` the last _four_ items?

Comment: Yes, there might be a space in there as theirs one at the end of the string.

Comment: ah! i did not see that. [*blush*] you may want to correct your comments, tho, since they don't match your code ... and perhaps add a note about the extra array items.